# Can't override .Equals in Structure

Tags: vb.net

I have been running FxCop over my code and it is reporting a number of CA2224 and CA1815 errors, due to structures possessing `Operator =` functions but no override for `.Equals`. Being a dutiful fellow I'm endeavouring to correct these but have run into a problem. I have created a structure thus:-

```
Public Structure MyStruct

    Public my_innards As Integer

    Public Shared Operator =(ByVal fs As MyStruct, ByVal ss As MyStruct) As Boolean
        Return fs.my_innards = ss.my_innards
    End Operator

    Public Shared Operator <>(ByVal fs As MyStruct, ByVal ss As MyStruct) As Boolean
        Return fs.my_innards <> ss.my_innards
    End Operator

End Structure
```

and I attempt to override the `.Equals` operator like so:-

```
Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal ss As MyStruct) As Boolean
    Return Me.my_innards = ss.my_innards
End Function
```

This produces the compilation error `function 'Equals' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a function in a base structure`

But when I try:-

```
Public Function Equals (ByVal ss As MyStruct) As Boolean
    Return Me.my_innards = ss.my_innards
End Function
```

this produces the warning `function 'Equals' shadows an overridable method in the base class 'ValueType'. To override the base method, this method must be declared 'Overrides'`.

In other words I must, and may not, declare the method as `overrides`. Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Try with `Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal ss As Object) As Boolean` - the argument of that function got to be `Object`

Comment: Isn't `ss` of type `Object` (`object` in C#)?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, righto. That's fixed it, thanks. Seems rather odd, though, that you can shovel any old thing into that function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify function parameter as `Object`:

```
Public Structure MyStruct

    Public Property Test As Integer

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If obj Is GetType(MyStruct) Then
            Return Test = CType(obj, MyStruct).Test
        End If
        Return False
    End Function

End Structure
```

However, I'm not sure it change anything with standard `Structure` comparison behavior - every value within the struct is compared by default.

Comment: As I mentioned, FxCop is grizzling about it, and by using DirectCast I can make the thing explode if something other than a `MyStruct` is passed in. I hope.

Comment: According to the CA1815 documentation:
"For value types, the inherited implementation of Equals **uses the Reflection** library, and compares the contents of all fields. **Reflection is computationally expensive**, and comparing every field for equality might be unnecessary. If you expect users to compare or sort instances, or use them as hash table keys, your value type should implement Equals. If your programming language supports operator overloading, you should also provide an implementation of the equality and inequality operators."